# Right way to generate html/js website with php

Tags: php, html, fwrite

I am making a section for website, with changeable info from admin panel, but the info won't change so much, so the section shouldn't be dynamic. I'm intended to generate html on info change, but to store all the html in one variable with `""` it gets messy. So maybe there is another way to do this, so its more maintainable?

Comment: I don't think this question should get such a low rating. PHP beginners keep stumbling into this "dynamic non-dynamic" question. I think there is a good answer for the "Right way to generate html/js website with php", and it's "Use a Framework".

Comment: As I mentioned below this is not the case where I can use framework, but I usually use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *cache* the site in a way that the cache will be hit first:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
<html>
...
Build your page dynamically as usual.
...
</html>
<?php

$site = ob_get_contents();
file_put_contents('webroot/site.html', $site);
ob_end_flush();
```

This builds a regular dynamic HTML/PHP page and writes that page into an .html file in the webroot, which will be hit directly the next time. In your admin interface you just need to delete this cached version whenever you update the information. The above script is invoked only if the .html version does not exist through .htaccess rewrite rules, e.g.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

So the logic works like this:

- admin updates contents in admin panel which are saved somewhere
- user visits site, no cached .html page exists, rewriting invokes the above PHP script
- the script creates the .html file and serves the page dynamically once
- the next user visits the site, gets the cached .html version
- admin updates contents in admin panel, cached site is deleted
- rinse, repeat

Answer (score 0):

I would write a "proper" php site, and if performance is a problem, I would use a caching proxy. Then if invalid cache is a problem, I would use/develop some tool that can invalidate the cache when someone saves samething at the admin.

I *strongly* suggest you to use a framework. I usually use Zend Framework, because I know it very well.

You could also use symfony, or yii. Search, compare, choose ;)

Comment: I usually use frameworks, but this is not the case, so generating html is the only choice I have.

Comment: Ok, so It's a business requirement. I would still use a framework, and then run a script that would mirror the dynamic site in a static one (with wget for example). How about that?